# Ctypes - getting a C backtrace from python code which uses ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm trying to debug code where python calls a C function using ctypes. The line in the python code I'm interested in looks something like:

```
returnValue = cfunction()
```

where cfunction is a C function. I want to know where in the cfunction code the cfunction returned from. How can I do this?

It looks like I can use gdb with python, but I'm not sure the right way to use gdb so I can set a breakpoint at the above line and show where the C function returned from in the C code. Of course I have the C code compiled with -g.

It's not a requirement that I use gdb for this, as long as I can do it with some free (as in beer or speech) tool in Linux.

(I'm running python 2.7.6, gdb 7.7, and the C code is compiled with gcc 4.8.2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `python` under any reasonable debugger (including gdb), whether by starting it that way or by attaching to it, it can create breakpoints in C code whether part of Python, loaded as an extension module, loaded via `ctypes, or otherwise. And, having done that, you can print out backtraces, step line by line or in or out, etc., anything else you want. It's just a normal debugger session. (Of course you might not have debugging symbols in your Python, but as long as you've got them for your .so, that's all you care about, right?)

For example (using `lldb`, but I think I've stuck to the subset of commands that are completely `gdb` compatible…):

```
$ lldb python3
Current executable set to 'python3' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 6828 launched: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3' (x86_64)
Process 6828 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x8cf0d1, 0x00007fff5fc01028 dyld`_dyld_start, stop reason = exec
    frame #0: 0x00007fff5fc01028 dyld`_dyld_start
dyld`_dyld_start:
-> 0x7fff5fc01028:  popq   %rdi
   0x7fff5fc01029:  pushq  $0x0
   0x7fff5fc0102b:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x7fff5fc0102e:  andq   $-0x10, %rsp
(lldb) c
Process 6828 resuming
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/libc.dylib')
Process 6828 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x8cf0d1, 0x00007fff8a7149aa libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8a7149aa libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10:
-> 0x7fff8a7149aa:  jae    0x7fff8a7149b4            ; __select + 20
   0x7fff8a7149ac:  movq   %rax, %rdi
   0x7fff8a7149af:  jmpq   0x7fff8a71119a            ; cerror
   0x7fff8a7149b4:  ret
(lldb) b printf
Breakpoint 1: where = libsystem_c.dylib`printf, address = 0x00007fff875cf8a8
(lldb) c
Process 6828 resuming
>>> libc.printf('spam')
Process 6828 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x8cf0d1, 0x00007fff875cf8a8 libsystem_c.dylib`printf, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00007fff875cf8a8 libsystem_c.dylib`printf
libsystem_c.dylib`printf:
-> 0x7fff875cf8a8:  pushq  %rbp
   0x7fff875cf8a9:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x7fff875cf8ac:  pushq  %r15
   0x7fff875cf8ae:  pushq  %r14
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x8cf0d1, 0x00007fff875cf8a8 libsystem_c.dylib`printf, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff875cf8a8 libsystem_c.dylib`printf
    frame #1: 0x0000000101a545e7 _ctypes.so`ffi_call_unix64 + 79
    frame #2: 0x0000000101a5549f _ctypes.so`ffi_call + 575
    frame #3: 0x0000000101a4f81f _ctypes.so`_ctypes_callproc + 879
    frame #4: 0x0000000101a4772a _ctypes.so`PyCFuncPtr_call + 314
    frame #5: 0x000000010000da08 Python`PyObject_Call + 104
    frame #6: 0x00000001000e1c3f Python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 16975
    frame #7: 0x00000001000e665d Python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2349
    frame #8: 0x00000001000e671f Python`PyEval_EvalCode + 63
    frame #9: 0x000000010010f5ba Python`PyRun_InteractiveOneObject + 474
    frame #10: 0x000000010010f93e Python`PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 110
    frame #11: 0x00000001001113e1 Python`PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 161
    frame #12: 0x000000010012867f Python`Py_Main + 3535
    frame #13: 0x0000000100000e32 Python
    frame #14: 0x0000000100000c84 Python
(lldb)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I get the gist of what you're doing, but I'm not still not sure how I can put a breakpoint in the python script I have. I suspect I know so little about how to use a debugger in general that I need to do a lot more work before I can legitimately ask this question on SO.

Comment: @raoulcousins: Do you want a breakpoint in the Python code, or in the C code? For the former, you want to use `pdb`, not a C-level debugger. For the latter, you need to read a tutorial on `gdb` or whatever other debugger you want, and/or to find a nice GUI IDE that wraps it up so you can just click next to the line of code and have it add the breakpoint… but the basic idea is that `b printf`. If there's an unambiguous C function named `printf` in my program, that command sets a breakpoint at the start of that function.

Comment: @raoulcousins: Things can get a bit more complicated, but for simple cases… well, if you can call the function from `ctypes` just by writing `mylib.cfunction()`, you can usually breakpoint the function from `gdb` just by writing `b cfunction`.

Comment: Ultimately, what I want to know is where the cfunction is returning from (it has many return points). I suppose I could put a breakpoint everywhere that cfunction could return from and go from there.

Comment: @raoulcousins: Once you're at a breakpoint, you can step line by line with `n` (that "steps over" any function calls instead of diving into them) until you get to one of the `return` statements. Or you can just set breakpoints on the `return` statements themselves. But really, you need to read a debugger tutorial and start playing around; there's no way anyone can teach you how to use a debugger in a conversation over SO comments.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is not that I don't understand the basics of using a debugger. I'm not sure if I don't understand your answer because I don't know enough about the debuggers, or because it's an example but it doesn't seem to provide an explanation. It's also an issue of stackoverflow etiquette. Do I ask for more details from you, or do I assume that if I knew more about debuggers, I would understand your answer, and I should accept it?

Comment: I really don't want to be combative or not grateful for your help. I simply don't understand your answer. The fact that others are upvoting it makes me assume that I'm the problem.

Comment: @raoulcousins: Well, it's only got 1 upvote, not like 300. But meanwhile, what do you not understand about my answer? I showed how to put a breakpoint on the start of a function imported via `ctypes`. You know enough about debuggers to put breakpoints on the `return` statements, or to step-over one line at a time within that function, from there. So… what part are you still missing?

Comment: I get it now. I just didn't realize you were interrupting python to drop down to the debugger and set the breakpoints. I was confused about how to set the breakpoints once I had loaded python. I'm still not able to have it stop on breakpoints. I'm not sure if I need to use python2.7-dbg instead of python, or if the problem is something else.

Comment: @raoulcousins: Ah, sorry, I just realized the ^C didn't show up in the output. Yeah, you have to hit ^C or signal Python from outside or otherwise break into the debugger. Anyway, you shouldn't need a debug build of Python, or debug symbols for it, unless you want to put breakpoints on (or see better traces for, etc.) Python's own C functions. The one important thing is that you have to have loaded the .so (via `ctypes` or otherwise) before the debugger will know about it, unless you tell it to pre-load the symbols, so you can't add breakpoints until then.